# how to shift elements of array (or c-string) left by a given number indexes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a function to shift the characters of my c-string left by a given number of characters. Currently the function will shift the characters left but I am losing one. I know it is some sort of indexing issue with my for loop, but I can't pin it down.

EDIT: By shift left I mean:

Given a starting c-string of a, b, c, d 
if shifted left one index this same array would equal b, c, d, a
if shifted left two indexes this same c-string would equal c, d, a, b

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void shiftleft (char myarray[], int size, int shiftBy)
{

char temp;

for (int i=size-1; i > 0; i--)
{
    temp = myarray[size+shiftBy];
    myarray[size+shiftBy] = myarray[i];
    myarray[i] = temp;
}


}

int main() {
    char myarray[20] = "test";
    int size = 4;
    shiftleft (myarray, size, 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < size+1; i++){
    cout << myarray[i];
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is my working function that shifts each element to the right, all I need to do is reverse this loop, and move the elements left, as in this way: <----

```
//function bloack
void shiftright (char myarray[], int size, int shiftBy)
{
    if(shiftBy > size){
        shiftBy = shiftBy - size;
    }
    if(size == 1){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        char temp;
        //for loop to print the array with indexes moved up (to the right) --> by 2
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            temp = myarray[size-shiftBy];
            myarray[size-shiftBy] = myarray[i];
            myarray[i] = temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use vectors/strings instead of raw char arrays.

Comment: I can't really tell what you mean by 'shift left' given your non-working code example. You should provide us an example of the output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) perhaps?

Comment: Could you post an example input and output (of what you want to do, and what is your code doing) ?

Comment: So a shift is placing the first element of an array as the last?

Comment: yes, it is moving all the elements in this direction: <--.

Comment: I can't use any standard library functions.

Comment: I have updated my OP to include my function which shifts my c-string right. All I want to do is reverse this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little fanangling, I was able to get it to work. Here is my functioning function :)

The issue was that I needed to assign element i to i+shiftBy, and only repeat the loop while i < size-shiftBy.

```
//function bloack
void shiftLeft (char myarray[], int size, int shiftBy)
{
    if(shiftBy > size){
        shiftBy = shiftBy - size;
    }

    if(size == 1){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        char temp;
        //for loop to print the array with indexes moved up (to the left) <-- by 2
        for (int i=0; i < size-shiftBy; i++)
        {//EXAMPLE shift by 3  for a c-string of 5
            temp = myarray[i];//temp = myarray[0]
            myarray[i] = myarray[i + shiftBy];//myarray[0] == myarray[2]
            myarray[i + shiftBy] = temp;//myarray[2] = temp(value previously at index i)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want shift string to left and don't rotate, you can use this code:

```
void shiftLeft (char *string,int shiftLength)
{

int i,size=strlen(string);
if(shiftLength >= size){
    memset(string,'\0',size);
    return;
}

for (i=0; i < size-shiftLength; i++){
    string[i] = string[i + shiftLength];
    string[i + shiftLength] = '\0';
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Suppose if j is your len of shift

```
char* name = strdup("Hello");
char* str_ptr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));  
strcpy(str_ptr, name);
int j = 3 // len of shift
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str_ptr); i++){
  printf("%c", str_ptr[(i+j)%strlen(str_ptr)]);
}
```