# Shifting char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

For example, if I have a string in an char array like "abcdef", then I would like to print a new string "bcdefa" then next would be "cdefab" and so on until it cycles through the string ending up at "fabcde"

Sorry I am new to C and not the best of array manipulation and unsure what would be the easiest approach.

I was thinking maybe rearranging the indexes at first? but I wasn't sure how to loop that. Or could I approach this in a more efficient way using some function from the string.h library?

Comment: It's possible. What code do you already have?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I have not yet started the code, just wanted to know how to get started on a general basis

Comment: classical traverse and swap will work like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745018/how-to-shift-elements-of-array-or-c-string-left-by-a-given-number-indexes

Comment: Lemme guess, it's that marquee display homework again:(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533350/how-to-output-a-string-in-a-marquee-fashion

Comment: Looks like a typo in the last example `fabced` should be `fabcde`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called array rotation, and there's a nice trick for that. You reverse both parts, and then you reverse the whole thing. Here's an example:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char* a, char* b) {
    char tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void rev(char* array, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        swap(array + i, array +(n - i - 1));
}

void rotate_one(char* str) {
    rev(str + 1, strlen(str) - 1);
    rev(str, strlen(str));
}
```

See <kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/LLHQ33668)</kbd>

Comment: Very nice, but doing his homework for him probably doesn't help him out in the long run. Not my downvote, incidentally.

Comment: ohh i see, and it is just a sub problem for my main problem. I need to apply the similar concept to a bigger scale with more restrictions but i figured if i could see it with no restrictions I could reapply in a way I need it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the string:

```
char str[] = "abcdef";
```

Save the first character, because it will be overwritten later:

```
char tmp = str[0];
```

Then move the rest of the string one character forward. Please not that `strcpy()` is not allowed here, because on overlapped strings the behaviour is undefinded.

```
memmove(str, &(str[1]), strlen(&(str[1])));
```

Then store the saved first character at the end:

```
str[strlen(str) - 1] = tmp;
```

And one rotation is done. And

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

will show `bcdefa`.